# Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field in a java class

Tags: java

```
public class College {
   public String collegename;
   public String branch;
   public String username;
   public String password;
 public College(String college,String branch,String user, String pass)
 {
 College.collegename = college;
 College.branch= branch;
 College.username= user;
 College.password= pass;
 }
}
```

this is my class and the error that is occouring is cannot make a static reference to the non-static field. Please tell me what is the problem and let me know how to slove it.

Thanks in advace.

Comment: There isn't any static fields here. Just change `College.` to `this.`

Comment: You need to capitalise the `college` constructor too. IE. `public College(...`

Comment: Yes, captilize first letter of College in your constructor and you are fine. If you want to ask when and where to use static, you may want to edit your post.

Comment: You are trying to treat those variables as static while they are not. If you do **ClassName.variableName** then it will assume that variable is static.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the constructor the wrong instances: you have to refer to class' instances as "this". 
Correct syntax:

```
public College(String college,String branch,String user, String pass)
{
 this.collegename = college;
 this.branch= branch;
 this.username= user;
 this.password= pass;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring class level variables and using it like static members.
Try

```
public class College {
   public String collegename;
   public String branch;
   public String username;
   public String password;
 public college(String college,String branch,String user, String pass)
 {
     this.collegename = college;
     this.branch= branch;
     this.username= user;
     this.password= pass;
 }
}
```

`this` keyword is use to refer class variables.

**Edit:**

If you want to use as mentioned in comment.

```
public class College {
  String collegename;
  String branch;
  String username;
  String password;
  private static College instance = null;
  protected College() {
      // Exists only to defeat instantiation.
   }
  public static College getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new College();
      }
      return instance;
   }
  public void SetData(String collegeName, String branch, String userName, String password)
  {
         this.collegename = collegeName;
         this.branch= branch;
         this.username= userName;
         this.password= password;
  }

  public String GetCollegeName()
  {
    return this.collegename;
  }
  // So on...
}
```

Set all data first anywhere in any class like,

```
College.getInstance().SetData("abcCollege","abcBranch","username","password");
```

Use it in another class like,

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend = new ArrayList<>(); dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("collegename", College.getInstance().GetCollegeName()));
```

Or simply make instance of College.

```
College college = new College("abcCollege","abcBranch","username","password")
ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend = new ArrayList<>(); dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("collegename", college. collegename));
```

**Although I don't know Java, but it should be something like this.**

Comment: Hazma Hasan i am using that class in another class to send and retrive data from the server when i use    ArrayList<NameValuePair>dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
   dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("collegename", College.collegename)); its is showing an error. change collegename to static in College class

Comment: Thn either make instance of College or make it singleton

Answer (score 0):

Replace all references of 'College' in the constructor with 'this'.
The 'this' keyword refers to the current object whereas using the class name 'College' directly refers to a static access of a class.